# Can I call componentShown() method from a class that extends JFrame instead of JPanel ? If yes, how?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, componentlistener

I want to show one `JLabel` and one `JComboBox` when one particular `RadioButton` is selected in previous frame, otherwise it should be hidden. Even when I implement `ComponentListener` in that class his abstract methods(`componentShown()`, `componentHidden()`) are never called.

Comment: Request you to read http://sscce.org/ first

Comment: this question doesn't make much sense - implementing methods doesn't imply them being called automagically at runtime :-) Please read and understand the chapter about EventListeners in the swing tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki. If you then still hit problems, come back with a SSCCE (as already suggested, can't be repeated often enough, though)

Comment: Had you tried [Component.isShowing()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing())? It seems to me you need this method, not the one's you playing with :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem can be handled pretty easily, without even getting into these event handlers. Just pass a variable from your initial frame, when the RadioButton is selected, to the new frame (maybe a boolean variable with true value). Then, in your new fame, simply show the components, based on the value of that variable.
I hope you can handle the passing of variables, by handling the constructor parameters of your new frame.

Hope this helps ! Any clarifications required, please comment.